# How to disable Luatex warning when combining Feynman diagram, beamer class and pdflatex

Tags: beamer, pdftex, luatex, warnings, tikz-feynman

I am making a presentation with Latex that contains some Feynman diagram. I create the Feynman diagrams with `tikz-feynman`. Now I face a problem when choosing an output file:

- The Feynman diagram requires Luatex.
- For a presenting the presentation I need pdflatex.

When choosing Luatex, no warnings occur but the output is a simple pdf file that is not suitable for presentation. The only option that works fine for a presentation is to choose pdflatex, but I have to except that there are a list of warnings: The main warning is as follows:

> “Package tikz-Feyman Warning: Luatex is required if you wish to have vertices automatically placed. You can disable this warning by setting /tikzfeynman/warnluatex=false on input line 4

(see MWE). This is the \begin{document} line.

I tried many things but I fail to disable this warning. How to do this? I am working in TexnicCenter.

Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman} 
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Feynman diagram}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}
\vertex (a) {a};
\vertex[above=of a, xshift=1cm] (b) ;
\vertex[above=of b, xshift=-0.7cm] (c) {c};
\vertex[right=of b, yshift=-0.5cm] (d) ;
\vertex[above=of d, xshift=0.5cm] (e) {e};
\vertex[below=of d, xshift=0.3cm] (f) {f};
\diagram*{
(a)--[fermion] (b)--[fermion] (c);
(b)--[boson]   (d)--[fermion] (e);
(d)--[fermion] (f)};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: "For a presenting the presentation I need pdflatex." why?

Comment: according to http://texniccenter.sourceforge.net/configuration.html texniccenter should have an ouput profile for lualatex. Can you try it?

Comment: Hi, welcome. What makes the PDF from Lualatex not suitable for presentation? `\tikzfeynmanset{warn luatex=false}` to disable that one warning.

Comment: (unrelated to latex, but please do check the directions of your fermions)

Comment: @ Carlisle. Yes, It is simple to choose luatex as the output profile. That is not the problem, But I need pdflatex to create a slideshow with effects. This does not work when using pdflatex (then the output is just one pdf file).

Comment: @JacquesSmeets Which kinds of effects are you using? Overlays etc. work just the same in lualatex

Comment: @JacquesSmeets Did you select lua**la**tex?

Comment: @ Torbj \orn T. When using Lualatex, I cannot make use of showing dynamic slides from the same frame source during the presentation (such a working with \pause etc.). With Luatex the output is one simple pdf file.

Comment: @JacquesSmeets Can you show an example of a frame which fails with lua**la**tex? I'm sure we can fix this

Comment: @Samcarter. Excuse for typing error: I use LuaLAtex. When using Lualatex, the pdf-output is fine (including the Feynman diagram). However, overlays etc, does not work. As an example: I often use \pause, but that has no effect.

Comment: @JacquesSmeets I'm not aware of any problems with `\pause` in lualatex. Can you add a short test document that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @JacquesSmeets Does `\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
 a\pause b
\end{frame} 
\end{document}` work for you?

Comment: there is no reason why the slideshow should work differently in luatex.

Comment: (Tip: use tab-completion of usernames for @-pings. I.e., if you Type @Tor you should see a little box with my username - hit the tab-key for auto-completion. Writing \o for ø won't work as these comments aren't LaTeX, and I wasn't notified of your comment.) NOt really sure what you mean there. As I understand it, with `a\pause b` such as samcarter's example above, you'll get a "simple PDF" with pdflatex as well - i.e., a PDF with two pages/slides, where the first shows only "a", and the second "ab". How does the output from `pdflatex` and `lualatex` differ?